# Two modules, Same line of code, one code works but other does not

Tags: excel, class, runtime-error, vba

I have just started using dictionaries and Class collections.  I wrote a code using both that worked fine (see code below).

```
For a = 2 To UBound(FullArray, 1)

        Set GEMclass = dict.Items(a) '<-------
        GEM = GEMclass.g

             'Do while loop
             Do

            'Check to see if Parent has an owner
             If (Not (dict.Exists(GEM))) Then

                     Nrow = 0
             Else

                      Nrow = dict(GEM).Num

                      Call Main
                      Call PartTwo
                      Call PartThree

             End If

             Loop Until (Nrow = 0) 'keep doing this unti no tree link

Next a

Call TurnOnFunctionality

End Sub
```

However, I tried to use the same line of code in another sub and it does not work (the line is in marked with an arrow).

```
Dim i As Integer

    If ((GemDict.Exists(GEM))) Then

    i = GemDict.Item(GEM)
    i = i - 2
    Set GEMclass = GemDict.Items(i) '<-------

            'Debug.Print GemDict.Item(GEM)

            'Debug.Print GemDict.Keys(i)

                If GEMclass.NumofP > 1 Then

                MsgBox "Greater 1"

                Else

                MsgBox "Only 1"

                End If

    End If

    GEM = GEMclass.P
```

I declared both GEMclasses in each code as so

```
Public GEMclass As Gclass
```

Any ideas?  I am stumped.

Comment: What error do you get? Does item `GEM - 2` exist?  You only check for `.Exists(GEM)`.

Comment: I get Run-time error 424 Object Required.

Comment: Does item `GEM - 2` exist in the Dictionary? You're subtracting 2 from the key you're testing.

Comment: This sub is part of a loop. I = gemdict.item(Gem) is equal to 3.  I want "I" to equal to 1; therefore, I am subtracting 2 from 3 to get to 1.  The next loop "I" should equal 2.

Comment: Put this line of code in right before your `Set` statement and find out:  `If Not GemDict.Exists(i) Then Debug.Assert False`

Comment: I am sorry, which line of code I should move?

Comment: Don't *move* anything. *Add* that line of debugging code right above `Set GEMclass = GemDict.Items(i)`.

Comment: Okay, Asset False was called.  What does that mean?

Comment: That means that at that point in your code, whatever the key `i` is isn't in the Dictionary.  You'll have to check your logic to figure out why - there isn't enough information in the question to determine that.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know where to look!